AR Application for body tracking and measurements
How to integrate emuguCV in unity and use it to track body or faces using AR? and can i use emuguCV for body measurements with an accuracy of atleast 90 to 97 percent like in virtual fitting room? and lastly can you suggest other engine for developing AR apps?
I hope that it is not hard to use EmuguCV for measurements and body tracking.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
